Can't click on elements in webview (Android TV)
I implemented a webview with Android Studio which loads a website full of clickable elements:
WEBVIEW.clearCache(true);
WEBVIEW.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
WEBVIEW.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
WEBVIEW.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
WEBVIEW.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
WEBVIEW.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
WEBVIEW.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
WEBVIEW.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
WEBVIEW.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
WEBVIEW.addJavascriptInterface(new WebViewInterface(this), "js_interface");
WEBVIEW.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
WEBVIEW.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                }
                @Override
                public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError e) {
                    
                }
                @Override
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
                    
                }
            });

My app works great on android mobile phones and android boxes.
even android tv's web browser (chrome), loads web page without any click issues.
but my webview app on Android TV loads page with click issue.
Any suggestion?
Update:
If I focus on elements (with left/right keys), it responds to my commands but direct click on elements are not working.
